# Convert Scalar-valued Function to Table-valued Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a scalar function which calculates running balances for customer accounts like this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_GetBalance] (@CustRef bigint, @ID bigint)
RETURNS decimal(18,2)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Balance decimal(18,2)
  SELECT @Balance = SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY CustReference ORDER BY Id 
                                      ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
FROM
CustomerLedgerEntries WHERE CustReference =@CustRef and ID <= @id

RETURN @Balance
END
```

To add this function to the table, I run this query:

```sql
ALTER TABLE CustomerLedgerEntries ADD Balance as (dbo.UDF_GetBalance(CustReference, ID))
```

And now I have a Balance column added to the table which displays the running balance for each customer, calculated using the DebitAmount and CreditAmount.

However, as the database grows, I am noticing serious performance issues because of this function.

Question: Please can you give me pointers how to convert this to a Table-valued function and create a column Balance and apply the TVF to it? I created this TVF:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UDF_GetBalance2 (@CustRef bigint)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
  SELECT balance = SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY CustReference ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
FROM CustomerLedgerEntries 
WHERE CustReference =@CustRef;
GO
```

I guess this should work, but how do I `ALTER TABLE CustomerLedgerEntries ADD Balance as...` using the TVF?

I need to consume the table as-is, with pre-filled Balance values from a C# application. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd calculate this at runtime instead of making sql server recalculate it every time a row is inserted.

Comment: I think only scalar functions are allowed in computed columns. A TVF would require a subquery expression, which is not allowed in computed columns.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't do that, and if you could, I would not recommend it. The proper pattern here would be to create a view, e.g. vw_CustomerLedgerEntries, which has the Balance column, either by applying the itv function, or immediately in the view itself. You'd then consume the view instead of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Why write a table valued function?  Just use a view:

```
select cle.*,
       sum(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) over (partition by CustReference order by Id) as balance
from CustomerLedgerEntries;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the responses from above, I created a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_CustomerLedgerEntry]
AS
Select * 
        , Sum(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) Over( Partition By CustReference Order by Id 
                                    rows Unbounded Preceding) As Balance 
 From CustomerLedgerEntries
```

And I just used EF code-first to consume the view as per this link: [USING SQL VIEWS WITH ENTITY FRAMEWORK CODE FIRST](http://laboremus.ug/?p=1708)

Thank you all for the help.